# unable to connect to sqlcl with a username containing $ using the EzConnect syntax

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database schema whose username contains $, ex: ABCD$EFG

```
./sql.bat ABCD$EFG/dbpassword@dbhostname:1521:dbservicename
```

The username is wrongly identified as ABCD instead of ABCD$EFG.

```
  USER          = ABCD
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhostname:1521:dbservicename
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I have tried "ABCD$EFG", "ABCD\$EFG". Nothing works.

How to escape $ symbol in the username?

Comment: Did you try `"ABCD$EFG/dbpassword@dbhostname:1521:dbservicename"` (quotes around the complete connection URL)

Comment: It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It could be necessary to escape the $ on linux/mac that mean an env variable which it will try and replace.

Here's it working and notice the \$

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0


SQL> create user "ABCD$EFG" identified by dbpassword;

User "ABCD$EFG" created.

SQL> grant connect,resource to "ABCD$EFG";

Grant succeeded.


SQL> 
Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0



dhcp-10-10-180-36:ords klrice$ sql "ABCD\$EFG"/dbpassword@//localhost:1521/xe

SQLcl: Release 18.4 Production on Wed Jan 16 14:14:16 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0


SQL>
```